# Select2 always shows "No results found" message

Tags: html, tags, jquery-select2

I need to create select2 where I can select multiple values. But I'm getting "no results found" message everytime, tried various solutions but nothing worked. I really don't have idea what's wrong.

```html
<select id="keywords-input" multiple="multiple" style="width:300px">
    {*
    <option selected="selected" value="Val 1">Val 1</option>*} {*
    <option selected="selected" value="Val 2">Val 2</option>*} {*
    <option selected="selected" value="Val 3">Val 3</option>*} {*
    <option selected="selected" value="Val 4">Val 4</option>*} {*
    <option selected="selected" value="asfsafafsa">asfsafafsa</option>*}
</select>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#keywords-input').select2({
            tags: true,
            tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
            data: ['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3'],
            maximumInputLength: 10,
            multiple: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image: The result]

Answer (score 6):

It was caused by another javascript that used select2 class, now it works. So it my code wasn't wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works just fine for me:

**HTML**

```
<select id="keywords-input" multiple="multiple" style="width:300px">
    {*
    <option selected="selected" value="Val 1">Val 1</option>*} {*
    <option selected="selected" value="Val 2">Val 2</option>*} {*
    <option selected="selected" value="Val 3">Val 3</option>*} {*
    <option selected="selected" value="Val 4">Val 4</option>*} {*
    <option selected="selected" value="asfsafafsa">asfsafafsa</option>*}
</select>
```

**JS**

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#keywords-input').select2({
            tags: true,
            maximumInputLength: 10,
        });
    });
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydc3q624/)

Comment: Turns out that even the most simplest example doesn't work for me. I use select2.full.min.js with select2.min.css (4.0.5)

Comment: Try loading select2 through CDN `<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>` and let me know if it works this way